# Как проверить, была ли форма успешно отправлена?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, form, валидация

Нужно определить событие успешной отправки формы. Не onsubmit - событие нажатия на кнопку отправки, - поскольку форма может не пройти валидацию и не быть после этого отправлена, а именно отправку после проверки.

Как можно это сделать средствами JS/JQuery/Php?

Сайт работает на Wordpress, тема Enfold, используется форма по умолчанию. Круто, если кто-то знает, как решить это именно в рамках данной темы, но если есть вариант решения просто для любой стандартной формы, тоже будет полезно.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_mail_failed', 'mail_failed' );

function mail_failed( $wp_error ) {
    error_log( print_r( $wp_error, true ) );
}
```

пример отсюда https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_mail_failed В переменной $wp_error большой объект с данными об ошибке (смотрите по ссылке).